# Installing numpy on Ubuntu without pip/anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu

Without using `anaconda or pip`, while installing `numpy` on Ubuntu and printing numpy version, i get this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basicVersions.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "/usr/bin/python3.7",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.4" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

On all the forums, installation steps given are in context of pip/anaconda. I don't find lot of reference with installation on Ubuntu via apt/apt-get. This looked like installation error, so i tried this as well, but no luck. Please help!

```
sudo apt install numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package numpy
~/python$ sudo apt install python3-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-numpy is already the newest version (1:1.17.4-5ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Could this be python version issue?
This was the code I was trying :

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

print("Python: ", sys.version)
print("Numpy: ", np.__version__)
print("Matplotlib: ", matplotlib.__version__)
```

Comment: In a terminal, what is the output of `python3 -c "import numpy as np; print(np.__version__)"`?

Comment: python3 -c "import numpy as np; print(np.__version__)"
1.17.4

Comment: On `ubuntu` I use a package manager (`synaptic`) to install a full developmental version of Python (this installs all basic `.h` files), `python3-all-dev`.  I don't recall if I install the `setuptools` separately.  From there I could also install `numpy`, but prefer to use `pip3`, so I can get the latest versions of packages like that.  The `ubuntu` repository lags (e.g. 1.13 versus the latest 1.18).  In other word I use `ubuntu` to get the base, background stuff, and `pip` for the latest.

Comment: you mean from synaptic manager you could install `numpy`? and it wont cause any versioning problem?

Comment: Did you run the program that triggered the error with `python3` (not `python`)?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: yes, i used `python3.7` as the command

Comment: OK, then what is the output of `python3.7 -c "import numpy as np; print(np.__version__)"`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I am getting same error as mentioned in the 1st block.

Comment: i assume, that's the problem. `python3 -c "import numpy as np; print(np.__version__)" 1.17.4` this gives me version no. but when i do python3.7 it throws back trace. how do i fix it then?

Comment: Short answer: use the command `python3` to run your program.  Long answer (well, comment, not answer): it looks like you have multiple versions of python installed, and something is wrong with the installation that gave you the command `python3.7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use the `python3` as command instead of `python3.7`
Issue can be marked closed with this conclusion.